# Get the keys corresponding to the 5 smallest values within a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

If I have a Python dictionary, how do I get and return the keys corresponding to the 5 smallest values?

Given the input:

```
employees = {'any': 5, 'restraint': 8, 'shadow': 6, 'authority': 8, 'being': 6, 'now': 5, 'passed': 5, 'away': 5, 'they': 6, 'living': 6, 'together': 7}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this solution:

```py
employees = {'any': 5, 'restraint': 8, 'shadow': 6, 'authority': 8, 'being': 6, 'now': 5, 'passed': 5, 'away': 5, 'they': 6, 'living': 6, 'together': 7}

employees_list = [(k, v) for k, v in employees.items()]
employees_list.sort(key=lambda s: s[1])
keys = [i[0] for i in employees_list[:5]]
```

So basically what is happening:

```py
employees_list = [(k, v) for k, v in employees.items()]
```

convert the dictionary to a list of tuples:

```py
[('any', 5), ('restraint', 8), ('shadow', 6), ('authority', 8), ('being', 6), ('now', 5), ('passed', 5), ('away', 5), ('they', 6), ('living', 6), ('together', 7)]
```

then sorting the list elements depending on the second element:

```py
employees_list.sort(key=lambda s: s[1])
```

resulting:

```py
[('any', 5), ('now', 5), ('passed', 5), ('away', 5), ('shadow', 6), ('being', 6), ('they', 6), ('living', 6), ('together', 7), ('restraint', 8), ('authority', 8)]
```

then extracting the first 5 keys.